# tcsh alias with awk fails when trying to find latest file recursively

Tags: awk, alias, tcsh

why following tcsh alias fail:

```
alias fl 'find . -name "new_avip.log" -print | xargs ls -lt | head -n 2 | awk '\''{print $9 }'\'''
```

with following error message :

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `new_avip.log' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

the goal is to find the most up-to-date file in all folders

Thanks

Comment: Don't worry about making an alias yet. Get your code to work from the command line and then wrap it as an alias. It's hard to tell, as I can't take the time to build a test bed with your file/dir structure, but I think  that `xargs` isn't working the way you expect it to work. back up and test from left to right each section of your pipe line (that is start with find, then add each pipeline element to see that is working the way you expect). I would also look to see if `xargs` has a verbose mode so you can see what command it is executing for each line of input from the pipeline. Good Luck!

Comment: try chaning to ` xargs -I {} ls -lt {}` . Got to walk the dog now. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

the command below works:

```
alias fl 'find . -name \!:1 -print | xargs ls -lt | head -n 1 | awk '\''{print $NF}'\'''
```